# linking problem with vision_opencv

Tags: ros, image-geometry, vision-opencv, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi my question is of two folds.
First, I am confused as why there are opencv3 and OpenCV-3.1.0-dev packages is in /opt/ros/indigo/share as i have read that opencv 2.4.8 is the default version of ROS indigo.

Also, I have opencv 2.4.13 version installed on ubuntu 14.04 with ROS Indigo, I want to use opencv for vision part for my project and for that i tried to install vision_opencv package from source. However when I try to build the package using catkin_make following error occurs

```
-- ==> add_subdirectory(vision_opencv/image_geometry)
```

CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/OpenCV-3.1.0-dev/OpenCVModules.cmake:183 (message):
The imported target "opencv_xobjdetect" references the file

```
 "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/libopencv_xobjdetect3.so.3.1.0"
```

but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:

- The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
- An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
- The installation package was faulty and contained

  "/opt/ros/indigo/share/OpenCV-3.1.0-dev/OpenCVModules.cmake"

but not all the files it references.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/ros/indigo/share/OpenCV-3.1.0-dev/OpenCVConfig.cmake:86 (include)
vision_opencv/image_geometry/CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/hemang/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/hemang/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1

---

What I dont understand is why is it trying to link with Opencv3 when system does not have opencv3 installed or ROS indigo comes with opencv3 now ??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258013/linking-problem-with-vision_opencv/) by [hpurohit](https://answers.ros.org/users/27412/hpurohit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-03-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

so I figured it out so in the CMakeLists.txt files of both cv_bridge and image_geometry, `find package(OpenCV REQUIRED)` should be `find package (OpenCV 2.4.13 REQUIRED)` . This is in my case as I have OpenCV 2.4.13 installed, one can replace it with any version one is using

---

Originally posted by [hpurohit](https://answers.ros.org/users/27412/hpurohit/) with karma: 16 on 2017-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0